# Are there any research papers rethinking browser architecture?

Tags: research

I am interested in any research that reviews the state of affairs when it comes to browsers today, be it their concurrency models, their performance, or anything relevant to such topics. Specifically, I am interested in whether any effors are being taken in academia to take on the shortcomings of browser design currently used in the wild.

[**Update, some more context**]: This question stemmed from a reading of the original Erlang paper, in which the descriptions provided for fault-tolerance and strong process isolation made me think of how browers work (some do provide process/tab isolation, but this is inherently tied to their own implementations, most of which can only do process isolation that relies on OS primitives). So, another way of way of answering parts of my question is pointing me to any *implementations* that might have gone a different way, be it adopting functional languages or some similar. Now that I clarified my question a bit more I found this link [1], which actually does not mention any other implementation but merely describes why C++ rules the browser field. Therefore I am still interested in any theoretical takes on the topic.

Perhaps I am asking in the wrong SE forum, in which case please advise me on where to post my question.

[1] https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/41883/why-are-most-browsers-developed-in-c

Comment: i don't think your question is off topic but surely it is too broad. Maybe you could make your question more specific ?